# useful open source libraries/projects on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, open-source

Which open-source projects do you feel C/C++ Windows developers should be aware of?

[Boost Libraries](http://www.boost.org/): generic library (smart pointers, command line parsing, threads, formatting, etc)

[Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/): full-feature SQL database.

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en): provides information about audio/video files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say

1. <strike>[GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)</strike>
2. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products).
3. [SQLite is awesome](http://www.sqlite.org/).
4. [libxml](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libxml2.htm).
5. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)
6. [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
7. [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/)
8. [Apache HTTP Server and APR, and all Apache top-levels](http://www.apache.org)
9. [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/)
10. [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/)

Actually, **just install Linux or another Free UNIX**

Comment: +1 for the humor, even if you <strike>provided some awesome suggestions</strike>

Answer (score 0):

[**CodeCogs**](http://www.codecogs.com/d-ox/stats/moments/kurtosis.php) is great for scientific, mathematical, and engineering applications:

```
#include <codecogs/stats/moments/kurtosis.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float x[5] = {3.4 , 7.1 , 1.5 , 8.6 , 4.9};
  double kurt = Stats::Moments::kurtosis<float>(5, x);
  // "Population kurtosis is: -0.928457"
  std::cout << "Population kurtosis is: " << kurt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Open Source Softwares for Windows Platforms](http://osswin.sourceforge.net/). It list number of Open Source Softwares for Windows Platform.